# Why does python allow an empty function (with doc-string) body without a "pass" statement?

Tags: python, syntax

```
class SomeThing(object):
    """Represents something"""

    def method_one(self):
        """This is the first method, will do something useful one day"""

    def method_two(self, a, b):
        """Returns the sum of a and b"""
        return a + b
```

In a recent review of some code similar to the above, a colleague asked:

> How come `method_one` is successfully parsed and accepted by python? Doesn't an empty function need a body consisting of just [`pass`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#pass)? i.e. shouldn't it look like this?

```
def method_one(self):
    """This is the first method, will do something useful one day"""
    pass
```

My response at the time was something like:

> Although the docstring is usually not considered to be part of the function body, because it is not "executed", it is parsed as such, so the `pass` can be omitted.

In the spirit of [sharing knowledge Q&A style](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/), I thought I'd post the more rigorous answer here.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

According to the [Python 2.7.5 grammar specification](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/grammar.html), which is read by the parser generator and used to parse Python source files, a function looks like this:

```
funcdef: 'def' NAME parameters ':' suite
```

The function body is a `suite` which looks like this

```
suite: simple_stmt | NEWLINE INDENT stmt+ DEDENT
```

Following this all the way through the grammar, `stmt` can be an `expr_stmt`, which can be just a `testlist`, which can be just a single `test` which can (eventually) be just an `atom`, which can be just a single `STRING`. The docstring.

Here are just the appropriate parts of the grammar, in the right order to follow through:

```
stmt: simple_stmt | compound_stmt
simple_stmt: small_stmt (';' small_stmt)* [';'] NEWLINE
small_stmt: (expr_stmt | print_stmt  | del_stmt | pass_stmt | flow_stmt |
             import_stmt | global_stmt | exec_stmt | assert_stmt)
expr_stmt: testlist (augassign (yield_expr|testlist) |
                     ('=' (yield_expr|testlist))*)
testlist: test (',' test)* [',']
test: or_test ['if' or_test 'else' test] | lambdef
or_test: and_test ('or' and_test)*
and_test: not_test ('and' not_test)*
not_test: 'not' not_test | comparison
comparison: expr (comp_op expr)*
comp_op: '<'|'>'|'=='|'>='|'<='|'<>'|'!='|'in'|'not' 'in'|'is'|'is' 'not'
expr: xor_expr ('|' xor_expr)*
xor_expr: and_expr ('^' and_expr)*
and_expr: shift_expr ('&' shift_expr)*
shift_expr: arith_expr (('<<'|'>>') arith_expr)*
arith_expr: term (('+'|'-') term)*
term: factor (('*'|'/'|'%'|'//') factor)*
factor: ('+'|'-'|'~') factor | power
power: atom trailer* ['**' factor]
atom: ('(' [yield_expr|testlist_comp] ')' |
       '[' [listmaker] ']' |
       '{' [dictorsetmaker] '}' |
       '`' testlist1 '`' |
       NAME | NUMBER | STRING+)
```

Comment: Note that any statement will do, not just string. Try 0 for example.

Comment: @comodoro I'm late to the party, but it's not strictly the same, in case of the string it become the docstring for the function/method that you can retrieve with `method_one.__doc__` of `help(method_one)` but with other statement the function may not have a docstring. I guess it's not often relevant but there is a difference