# How to avoid "SyntaxError expected an indented block"?

Tags: python, syntax-error

I've checked that I have 4 spaces. But the error still shows up. I'm using classes for the first time. I do not know why, but when I copy-paste working code, the error still shows up.
Here's the code:

```
import pygame, sys, random, time
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()

s=600

BLUE  = (0, 0, 255)
RED   = (255, 0, 0)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)

disp=pygame.display.set_mode((600,600))
disp.fill(BLACK)
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")

class Apple(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def _init_(self):
        super()._init_()
        self.image=pygame.image.load("Leaf.png")
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center=(random.randint(10,s-10),(10,s-10))
    def ate(self):
        
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def _init_(self):
        super().__init__() 
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Ant.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (160, 520)
    def move(self):
        pressed_keys=pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if self.rect.up > 0:
            if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
                self.rect.move_ip(0, -5)
        if self.rect.down<s:
            if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
                self.rect.move_ip(0,5)
        
        if self.rect.left > 0:
              if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
                  self.rect.move_ip(-5, 0)
        if self.rect.right < s:        
              if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
                  self.rect.move_ip(5, 0)
P1=Player()
A1=Apple()
```

The error is in the line `class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):`.

I tried 4 spaces and tab. It still didn't work. I do not know how to fix the code. I need help.

Comment: in which line you get the error?

Comment: After `def ate(self):` you can't go straight to a different class definition. Put `pass` into the body of that method if you want to leave it functionless for now.

Comment: You didn't define a body for `Apple.ate`. You can't leave it empty; you need at least one statement, such as `pass`, an expression statement like `...`, a doc string, etc.

Comment: Unrelated, the correct method name is `__init__`, not `_init_`.

Comment: Semi-duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735170/why-does-python-allow-an-empty-function-with-doc-string-body-without-a-pass; it discusses various alternatives to `pass` to define an "empty" function, without directly addressing the fact that you can't just write nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A function definition *must* contain a body, even if it's a trivial body like `pass`.

```
class Apple(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Leaf.png")
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.center = (random.randint(10, s-10), (10, s-10))

    def ate(self):
        pass
```

Without `pass` following the `:`, the parser is looking for the body, but the next text it finds is the unindented definition of `Player`, resulting in the observed error.

See [Why does python allow an empty function (with doc-string) body without a "pass" statement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17735170/why-does-python-allow-an-empty-function-with-doc-string-body-without-a-pass) for more information about what can serve as a "minimal" function body aside from the `pass` statement.

Comment: Oh. I forgot. After adding pass it worked. Thanks!